# Show blank row for 'unfound' data details

Tags: sql, datagrid

-- I was really not sure how to phrase my query title so feel free to change that! --

**Aim**: Show all 'sub-data' on a gridview and also a row to show there is 'no data' for properties where there is no data. So if you did a wildcard search for Property 1 and there was a property '1' with 2 rows of details and also a property '11', but with no details then there would be three rows on the datagrid (two for property '1' and one for property '11') The row for property '11' would have the UPRN and then the other rows would have 'No data for this UPRN'

Issue: On user search the grid shows details from 'TblAssociatedData' however what I want to do is when no data is found for one of the potential UPRNs in 'TblProperty' I want to return a row for that as well with 'No Data Found' so the user can see the search was valid is this property as well.

This is not the issue where there is no data at all to show, I have that working correctly.

I assume somewhere someone's asked this but I've tried different phrases and searches but can't find what I'm after.

**Code I use now:**

```
SELECT *  FROM TblAssociatedData AS a 
INNER JOIN TblProperty As p
on p.UPRN = a.UPRN  
WHERE           
a.SurveyDate between @sDateFrom and @sDateTo AND        
(a.UPRN LIKE  '%' + @sUPRN + '%'   or
p.PostCode LIKE '%' + @sPostcode + '%'  or
p.ShopName LIKE '%' + @sPropertyName + '%'  or
p.Street LIKE '%' + @sStreet + '%'  or
p.Reg LIKE '%' + @sRegion + '%'  or
a.SurveyCompany LIKE '%' + @sSurveyCompany + '%')
```

Not being able to get my head around how to add the next part I've done a untested layout as if it was in the .aspx page itself to hopefully show what my thought process, in terms of results, is.

**Code layout to show thought process**

```
sSQL1 = SELECT * FROM TBLProperty WHERE UPRN LIKE '%vUPRN%' 
-- select and then loop
dsNames1 = New SqlDataSource
dsNames1.ConnectionString = sConnString
dsNames1.SelectCommand = sSQL1

For Each datarow1 As Data.DataRowView In dsNames1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)

Dim vCount As Int = SELECT * FROM TBLProperty WHERE UPRN LIKE "'& datarow1("UPRN") &'"

If vCount > 0 Then

    For Each datarow1 As Data.DataRowView In dsNames1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
        --loop through database and output i.e.
        DateOfIssue = datarow("UPRN")
        DateOfIssue = datarow("DateOfIssue")
    Next

Else

    --put default text here 
    DateOfIssue = vUPRN
    DateOfIssue = "-"

End If
```

Essentially when I don't get a return for a found property I want to output something like the below for the UPRNs.

```
SELECT 'No data found.' as ColumnName1, '' as ColumnName2, '' as ColumnName3, '' as ColumnName4
```

Comment: You need to look up how to use a `left join`.  As an aside, all those wildcard searches (e.g. `LIKE  '%' + @sUPRN + '%'` will murder performance unless you have very small data sets.  And given that you are using `or` to join them together, if any of the variables are blank, you will just get all the data.

Comment: I understand the bad aspects of LIKE but sadly this is required in this instance.

Comment: I am up to: So if I stick to UPRN 99 and 999 using the below code I get two UPRNS:

SELECT * FROM TblProperty WHERE UPRN LIKE '%99%'
This is correct

If I try:


 

SELECT p.UPRN, ISNULL(a.UPRN,'Not Found') As Column3  FROM TblProperty AS p 
LEFT JOIN TblAssociatedData As a
on   a.UPRN = p.UPRN 
WHERE   
a.UPRN LIKE '%99%'
I expect 14 results for '99' and then there would be none for '999' but I want one to be there.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data for both tables?

Comment: Your where clause is referencing the wrong table, see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
    p.UPRN,
    COALESCE(a.UPRN,'Not Found') AS Column3
FROM TblProperty AS p
LEFT JOIN TblAssociatedData AS a
    ON a.UPRN = p.UPRN
WHERE p.UPRN LIKE '%99%'
```

Comment: Done a quick test and that looks like the answer. I'll tick once tested in full. Thanks!